# How can I remove Wine 1.4rc3 and install Wine 1.3.37 from Ubuntu PPA?

Tags: wine, ppa, uninstall

I'm running Lucid. I had installed Wine 1.3.37 from Ubuntu Wine PPA and I had my programs working. I wanted to install Wine 1.4rc3 so that I could install Office 2010. So I compiled 1.4rc3 from source. Then I ran into regressions that stopped some programs from working.

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get Wine 1.3.37 to reinstall. I have completely removed Wine, I have used Synaptic to "completely remove" packages, and I have tried to reinstall the current version from Ubuntu Wine PPA which should be Wine 1.3.37. When I go to "About" under winecfg, it always shows Wine 1.4rc3, and some of my programs don't work.

Thanks for the help.

Lucid Lynx
Backported kernel from Oneiric (3.0.0.-15) with Intel Glasen drivers for Sandy Bridge

Answer (score 1):

winecfg will use the profile it's told. Do you use a single wine directory for everything? I'm told that's not a good idea. Try to use another profile (for instance, by renaming ~/.wine to something else.) and see if that works.

Comment: Solved. There was no "uninstall" target in the Makefile for 1.4rc3 but the output of "whereis wine" told me where on my computer the compiled source was installed. I manually deleted it, reinstalled Wine 1.3.37. I'm good to go. Thank you.